# Meta syntax, or syntax for documenting syntax

Tags: syntax, documentation

While going through and properly documenting old code, I was wondering, what standards are there for documenting syntax?

- regular expressions: there's no single standard, and it's a little confusing to read.
- the one used in python documentation ([here's an example](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements)): it looks nice, but I haven't been able to find the specification anywhere.

Are there any others, and which one is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) is one option. [Syntax diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) is another.